# Is there a way to revoke consent to an application from a developer account?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign account and it allows me to log in for developer sandbox functionality. I am working with JWT authentication and trying to get granting and revoking consent working, but based off of the docusign page at https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent, I can't find my accounts profile preferences anywhere, and don't seem to have the same options available. Is this ability in a different place for revoking consent to an application if you are using a developer account? I have granted consent but can't find anywhere that I can revoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've granted Individual Consent, that can be revoked from the Manage Profile > Connected Apps section of your account. Note that Manage Profile is separate from My Preferences, but they're both accessed by clicking your profile picture in the upper right of the console.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.